# How I add custom link in Issue-link-section

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

I am creating a JIRA(Version- 7.2.2) plug-in, Here I want to insert my custom link in Issue-link-section. For your better understanding please view the below image.

[Click to View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8LDc.png)

Comment: From the picture, it looks like you want to add an administrator capability (define new link type) to the user's working interface, which I don't think is possible. If you just want to add a single new issue type, please clarify your question.

Comment: Hi Mike, 
Thanks to response,
Actually I am login as administrator. and i want to add here <My Application Link> in Link dialog which you have already seen in image.

Comment: I think Saleh Parsa's answer below is probably right, then.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add you custom link on that dialog you need to edit the bundled plugin associated with that dialogue. Technically that dialogue is part of the `jira-issue-link-web-plugin` which you can find the JAR file as `jira-issue-link-web-plugin.jar` in your installation directory. If I'm not mistaken you need to edit the velocity file in that JAR file and add your links over there. There is no way to add it from the UI unless you want to edit the JAR file and upload it as a newer version in your JIRA. Please note that it's bundled plugin and changing it may cause some malfunction in your production then be careful and test it in staging first.

Comment: Hi Saleh, 
Thanks for answer,
I am totaly agreed with you, So any other solutions to place a link.

Comment: No, if that's what you want to achieve I'm afraid to say that you need to consider editing and customising the bundled plugins.

Comment: ok saleh, so you mean to say i w'll not be able to achieve this.. am i right?

Comment: Well, I said you can achieve it if you edit the bundled plugin - Or even develop a new plugin with similar functionality.  You can't achieve it by editing something in Admin console ;-)

Comment: Is there any reference  for bundled plugin, so we can refer to get source code and implementing as per our requirements?

Comment: AFAIK, some licenses can get JIRA Source code (Commercial License for example) or as long as you have access to JIRA source code you might be able to get it. (not sure if they will release all bundled source codes or not)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs. much appretiated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes shailendra,You can try below solution for your query-

```
 <web-item key="example-create-link" section="create-issue-link-types" weight="100">
 <label key="MyCustomLink"/>
 <link linkId="link-issue">url</link>
 </web-item>
```